# Change UILabel font size based on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have a `UIScrollView` with a `UILabel` in it. The `UILabel` is initialised with font size 22. What I want is for the font to get smaller and smaller until font size 19 during scrolling down. When the user scrolls back up it gets larger and larger until font size 22.

I tried implementing this, but the font gets smaller then 19 or larger then 22 on scrolling. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    ScrollDirection scrollDirection;
    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionRight;
    } else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionLeft;
    }

    CGFloat fontSize = _textLabel.font.pointSize;

    if (scrollDirection == 1) {
        if (fontSize == 22) {
            fontSize = _textLabel.font.pointSize;
        } else {
            fontSize = _textLabel.font.pointSize + 0.05;
        }
    } else {
        if (fontSize == 19) {
            fontSize = _textLabel.font.pointSize;
        } else {
            fontSize = _textLabel.font.pointSize - 0.05;
        }
    }

    _textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Bold" size:fontSize];
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `NSLog` to print the fontSize to the console to see why it might be getting a different value than you're expecting?

Comment: Well, the problem is that it allow it to go larger then 22 and smaller then 19. So it seems like `fontSize == 19` is incorrect...

Comment: Try `if (fontSize >= 22)` and `if (fontSize <= 19)`.

Comment: I'm such a dumbass, of course that's the problem. Thanks! I'm going to put on my hat of shame and sit in a corner now.